# The while loop doesn't end but the condition is met

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to code vigenere cypher so I need to have two lists of the same length. I thought everything will be okay with my solution but the while loop doesn't despite of the fact than condition is met. Because of that I got two list with different numbers of letters. Why this works like that and how to improve that. I am new programmer who learnt from books, so I haven't ever seen that while loop doesn't work properly. My code:

```
plaintext = "This is secret message"
plaintext = plaintext.upper()
key = "secret"
key = key.upper()
def encrypt_vigenere2( key, plaintext ):
    a = []
    b= []
    i = 0
    for letter in (plaintext):
        if letter != " ":
            a.append(letter)
    while i<len(a):
        for element in key:
            if element != " ":
                b.append(element)
                i +=1
    return a,b
print(encrypt_vigenere2(key,plaintext))
```

Comment: Your code join KEY, until the total length reach the size of a, what for ?

Comment: This isn't doing any encryption. It's just copying the letters in `plaintext` to `a` and the letters in `key` to `b`.

Comment: I know, the name of function is wrong because I haven't finished the code. This is the first half of exercise, because i need to have one letter from key and one letter from plaintext to find a letter in a grid(It's is vigenere cipher). But I found a problem at the beginning so I haven't changed the name of funcion yet.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop does as expected, for you now you join the key until you reach the size of `a`,

```
b: ['S','E','C','R','E','T','S','E','C','R','E','T','S','E','C','R','E','T','S','E','C','R','E','T']
```

That will be useful for the next part : encryption

```
def encrypt_vigenere2(key, plaintext):
    ...
    result = ""
    for l, k in zip(a, b):
        result += chr(((ord(l) - 65 + ord(k) - 65) % 26) + 65)
    return result
```

---

You can just use `replace(" ", "")` to remove the spaces, and to repeat the key, use `itertools.cycle`

```
from itertools import cycle

def encrypt_vigenere2(key, plaintext):
    result = ""
    for l, k in zip(plaintext.replace(" ", ""), cycle(key)):
        result += chr(((ord(l) - 65 + ord(k) - 65) % 26) + 65)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your code right, but seems for me like you did not try to encrypt something. It looks like you tried to get the keystream, and correct me if I am wrong. But here is the code how to get the keystream:

```
def encrypt_vigenere3(key, plaintext):
    # variables
    a = [letter for letter in plaintext.upper() if letter != " "]
    b = [element for element in key.upper() if element != " "]
    keystream = []

    # creating the keystream
    i = 0
    current_num = 0
    while i <= len(a):
        if current_num == len(key):
            current_num = 0
        keystream.append(b[current_num])
        current_num += 1
        i += 1

    return keystream
```

I created the variables by "list comprehension". You should go look that term up, it makes your code way cleaner.

Comment: It is almost what I wanted. Your solution gives output which consist of 1 list which contains of key(secret). I wanted to get two list. One which you produce, second was a normal list of every letter in plaintext. But thank you, the other part is easy and I can produce it on my own :)

Comment: You are welcome! :) And you already have a list with every letter in plaintext. It is called "a". By the way you really shouln't name your variables a and b, can be confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea for a vigenere encrypter program sounded nice to me so I did some coding and here is my result:

```
def encrypt_vigenere(plaintext, key):

    letter_matrix = [[chr(65 + i) for i in range(26)] for j in range(26)]

    for index, column in enumerate(letter_matrix):

        for i in range(index):
            letter_matrix[index].append(column[0])
            del letter_matrix[index][0]

    plaintext = plaintext.upper()
    key = key.upper()
    keystream = ""
    ciphertext = ""

    current_letter = 0
    for letter in plaintext:
        if current_letter == len(key):
            current_letter = 0

        keystream += key[current_letter]
        current_letter += 1

    for letter_plaintext, letter_keystream in zip(plaintext.replace(" ", ""), keystream):
        ciphertext += letter_matrix[ord(letter_plaintext)-65][ord(letter_keystream)-65]

    return ciphertext
```

You said that you were new to coding, so here are the things you might not now:

- like previous said, list comprehension
- chr() -> takes a number and assigns it to it corresponding ascii value
- ord() -> the opposite of chr(). Takes letter and transforms it to ascii number
- zip() -> goes trough two lists simultaneously